# How to handle kmeans when a cluster has zero elements in it

Tags: java, k-means

I'm trying to implement KMeans in Java and have encountered a case that throws all of my results out. This happens when, given some randomly chosen initialized centroids, the data gets into a state where one of the centroids doesn't actually define a cluster. For example, if K=3, it could be that 2 of the centroids are closer to all of the data points, in which case during that iteration, I will only have 2 clusters instead of 3.

As I understand KMeans though, when we reset the centroids we need to sum up all of the data points per cluster and divide by the size of the cluster (to get the average). So, this means that we would have a cluster of size 0 and would get our new centroid to be

```
[0/0, 0/0, ... 0/0]
```

I have 2 questions about handling this case:
(1) How would we possibly recover from this if we've lost one of our clusters?
(2) Is there some way to account for the division by 0?

The code I have for this logic is as follows:

```
// do the sums
for (int i = 0; i < numDocuments; i++) {
    int value = label[i]; // get the document's label (i.e. 0, 1, 2)
    for (int j = 0; j < numWords; j++) {
        tempCentroids[value][j] += data[i][j];
    }
    tally[value]++;
}

// get the average
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numWords; j++) {
        tempCentroids[i][j] /= (double) tally[i]; // could have division by zero
        System.out.println("tally[i] for centroid " + k + " is " + tally[i]);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*“For example, if K=3, it could be that 2 of the centroids are closer to all of the data points, in which case during that iteration, I will only have 2 clusters instead of 3”*

I think you can always keep the centroid you chose for the third cluster to be in the third cluster and not in some other cluster. That way, you maintain the number of clusters and you don’t run into the weird case you mentioned. (I am assuming you chose the random centroids to be actual K data points from your dataset)

You might also want to look at K-means ++ algorithm which is the same as the Kmeans algorithm except for the initialization of the cluster-center step. This will lead to (probably) better classifications.